# how to manage the order back-end when using an ERP?

Tags: orders

I plan to export orders from Magento into our ERP using the www.xtento.com modules.

Our ERP will take the order, and then manage the invoicing, packlists, shipping, etc. Magento will send the first order confirmation email - and the rest will then come from the ERP. It's going to be mostly one way.

How do you then handle the disconnect between Magento <> ERP? Customers will not see the correct status etc on their Magento account page. I'm thinking there will be invocing number diconnects etc that I'm not sure how to handle right now.

Any ideas, experience in that area?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is one way, this is exactly what you face: Magento doesn't know ANYthing about the order. No status, not whether it is paid or not, etc.

What you can do is either remove everything from magento, which gives the customer a sense, which status his order has or write the data back to magento.

Comment: ok thanks, and is there some kind of 'semi-official' or correct way of disabling those features that you can suggest?

Comment: You can edit the order via one of the various APIs or you write your own importer...